# How to make StackPanel to change background like ListView item in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `StackPanel`. I want its background changes when I click on it, like the clicked items in `ListView`.

Comment: @MTCoster I simply add StackPanel below a ListBox, and when I click on it, it has no any appearance response by default. When I click on listbox item, the background color of the item changes and the text becomes smaller, just like that it is pressed down.

Answer (score 0):

You must handle `Stackpanel Tapped event` and do the logic there.
For example

```
private void panel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
 panel.Background = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need a Xaml only approach you could add the [Behaviours SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors).

Handily **Blend for Visual Studio 2015**  makes this easy by clicking *Assets* then prompts to add the [Nuget Package Behaviours](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/)

Sample of changing `StackPanel` background from *Red* to *Green* using *Tapped* event

first check you have the following 2 namespaces at the top of your page

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

then add the following

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myPanel" Height="200" Width="200" Background="Red">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=myPanel}" PropertyName="Background" Value="Green" />
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</StackPanel>
```